# Make an image move to another place when it is clicked on, using javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-animate

So I have a PHP page with images. And when each image is clicked on, I want each of them to move across the page and then become hidden.

```
<div class="lagoon">    
<img src="images/lagoon.jpg" alt="lagoon" id="LL"/>
<p class="text">Lagoon</p>
</div>
```

This is the code for one of my images. I now need to go into Javascript and make it move when it is clicked on.

```
$ ("LL").click(function (){
$ ("div").animate ({left:'250px'});
});
```

I have tried this, amongst many other things, please help.

Comment: Please consider taking a look at the jQuery manual.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector is incorrect. Use the # to target the `id` of an element.

```
$("#LL").click(function (){
  $("div").animate({left:'250px'});
});
```